# Google Maps Android - tracking location changes

Tags: java, android, dictionary, location

I'm developing a tracking application, for which I would also like be able to continue tracking when the application is sent to background. For this purpose I implemented a LocationListener. But clearly I'm missing something here, because during runtime none of the debug printlns appear, so the application never enters any of the inherited LocationListener functions.

```
 michal.myapp.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

import michal.myapp.R;
import michal.myapp.db.DataSource;
import michal.myapp.model.Track;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams; 
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

/**
 * @author Michał Szydłowski
 * 
 * Class representing user's map activity with location change detection and sensors. 
 *
 */
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
                                                         SensorEventListener{

private GoogleMap map;  
private DataSource dataSource;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer; 
private ArrayList <LatLng> trackPoints;
private boolean zoomEnabled;
private Button saveTrackButton;


private static final long INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float ACCURACY = 20;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);           
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);        
    initialize();
    check();     



    saveTrackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveTrackButton);
    saveTrackButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getDataFromPopupWindow();
        }

    });

}

private void check() {


    if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
       System.out.println("yes");
    }
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    Log.i("provider", "" + provider);
    if (provider.equals("")) {
        System.out.println("nope");
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void initialize()
{
     dataSource = new DataSource(this);
     sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
     senAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
     sensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer , SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);        
     trackPoints = new ArrayList <LatLng> ();
     zoomEnabled = true;

}

private void getDataFromPopupWindow()
{        
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
    = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
     .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.save_track_window, null);  
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
              popupView, 
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
              LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);          

    final EditText editName = (EditText) popupView.findViewById (R.id.trackName);
    editName.requestFocus();


    Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }

    });
    Button btnSave = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.save);
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String trackName = editName.getText().toString();               
            saveTrack(trackName);
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        }

    });   
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.update();
    popupWindow.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(saveTrackButton, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}

/**
 * Saves the track to database when finished
 */
private void saveTrack(String trackName){  
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    String date = String.valueOf(year) + "-" + String.valueOf(month) + "-" + String.valueOf(day) ;                  
    Track recordedTrack = new Track(trackName, trackPoints, date);
    dataSource.open();
    dataSource.insertTrack(recordedTrack);      
    dataSource.close();
}

/**
 * Centers the view of the map around the current user's location.
 * @param loc LatLng object representing user's current coordinates.
 */
private void zoom (LatLng loc)
{
    if(zoomEnabled)
    {                   
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc, 16));      
        zoomEnabled = false;
    }
}



/** Initializes the GoogleMap object if it hasn't been already done. 
 * If successful, enables location tracking.     
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (map == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (map != null) {
            //setUpMap();

            setUpMap();
        }

    }
} 

private void setUpMap()
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, INTERVAL, ACCURACY, this);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    System.out.println("setupmap");
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dataSource.close();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dataSource.open();
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}



@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {        
    Sensor mySensor = event.sensor;      
    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        if(event.values[0] > 15 || event.values[1] > 15 || event.values[2] > 15)
        {
//              Intent intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
//              startActivity(intent);
        }
    }       
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LatLng loc = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    trackPoints.add(loc);
    map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().addAll(trackPoints).width(5).color(Color.BLUE));
    zoom (loc);
    System.out.println("location changed");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("status changed");
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("provider enabled");
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      System.out.println("provider disabled");
}
```

}

I have the following permissions in my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCELEROMETER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

It is also worth mentioning, that I already try to attach an OnMyLocationChangeListener to my GoogleMap object, and it did track location changes, but not if the application was sent to background. Any ideas?

Comment: You should make a service not an activity i think

Comment: Yes... but my colleague has no service (more or less the same implementation as I do) and it works nicely. It shows toasts even if in background.

Comment: I thought android destroys activities in the background. Maybe he implemented the kind of a code like Facebook chat app uses so it stays in the foreground but hidden some way?

Comment: Okay, but let's put that problem aside for a while. First I need to know, why even while normally in the foreground, nothing happens and onLocationChange is never invoked.